# 一部のシンタックスに誤った補完がなされる

Tags: python, python3, vscode

環境は Python3.8, VScode, MacOS です。

以前までは、
i　と打つと、　ifの補完
e　と打つと　elseやelifの補完がなされていました。しかし、今朝気づけば、ifには補完がなく、eと打てば、ellipsis が補完され、if, elif, elseが候補にすら上がってきません。再起動してもダメでした。どうすれば解決できますでしょうか？

関係あるかは分かりませんが、最近別のフォルダで、setting.jsonを編集しました（補完機能を追加するためです）
これによって別のフォルダの補完まで影響されるもの何でしょうか？

具体的にはVScodeで、とある普通のフォルダ（フォルダAとします）の中に `.vscode` という名前のフォルダを作り、そこにlaunch.jsonというファイルを作りました。
そしてこう書きました。

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Download and Run Current File ",
            "type": "ev3devBrowser",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/home/robot/${workspaceRootFolderName}/${relativeFile}"
        }
    ]
}
```

また、次にsettings.jsonというファイルを作り、

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python"
}
```

を入力しました。するとフォルダA以外のフォルダでも補完が鈍くなりました。
この操作の目的は、補完の追加でした。

参考記事:
[【EV3 MicroPython】VSCodeでpybricks-apiの自動補完ができるようにする](https://qiita.com/Sunrise98/items/1c9424cc7f21f07a1b02)

Comment: [global設定](https://qiita.com/satokaz/items/6a6a0d9b6489ec2d1803#settingsjson-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE%E5%A0%B4%E6%89%80)と[ワークスペース設定](https://qiita.com/satokaz/items/6a6a0d9b6489ec2d1803#%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A-vscodesetingsjson)の2種類のsettings.jsonがあるようですが、global設定を変えれば有り得るのでは？ 何をどう変えたかの具体的な詳細が追記されれば的確な助言や回答が得られ易いでしょう。

Comment: 期せずしてマルチルートワークスペースの設定になってしまって、それらのフォルダが変更したワークスペースに所属しているとか？ [vscodeの利用に必須な"ワークスペース"の概念](https://prius.cc/itya/20181218_vscode-workspace), [Visual Studio Codeの設定「虎の巻」：IDE編 (1/3)](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1708/23/news026.html), [VS Codeのワークスペース](https://qiita.com/YuichiNukiyama/items/ef16a0219f46ea03a045), [Multi-root Workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)

Comment: あるいは、参考記事では`python.pythonPath`がルートからのフルパスですが、質問内容では相対パスなのが関係していたりはしませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに、参考記事にあるようにフルパスを入力しませんでした。それが関係あるかもしれないのですが、実はフルパスの取得方法が分かりません。どうやって確認できますでしょうか

Comment: この記事とかで分かるでしょう。[Find full path of the Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2589711/9014308)